# rm -rf takes a long time

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, io, rm

I have a directory `./aggregated/` in which I have 7550 sub-dirs each containing 250 files. `aggregated` has 5.5GB in total.

I've tried deleting `aggregated` via `rm -rf aggregated` and it is taking hours. This is on an external 2.5 HDD connected via USB3. Its file system is ext4. It is encrypted. The main disk drive of the machine is SSD. I have so far not been able to successfully delete the drive.

The machine is otherwise not busy and has plenty of CPU and RAM resources. The drive in question is sdb. It is almost brand new - have been using it from time to time for less than 1 year and so far haven't had issues with it and I don't believe is a drive problem.

```
pc ➜  code git:(master) ✗  lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   731M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                                          8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                                          8:5    0   465G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt                                253:0    0   465G  0 crypt 
    ├─mint--vg-root                           253:1    0 433.1G  0 lvm   /
    └─mint--vg-swap_1                         253:2    0    32G  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1                            253:3    0    32G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb                                             8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                                          8:17   0 931.5G  0 part  
  └─luks-04638d71-b455-4a87-b0fa-8f0b8d96f97b 253:4    0 931.5G  0 crypt /media/myuser/toshiba
```

The entry in `/etc/mtab` is:

```
/dev/mapper/luks-04638d71-b455-4a87-b0fa-8f0b8d96f97b /media/myuser/toshiba ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

EDIT:

I found that I could delete everything if I `cd` into the folder and do `rm -rf *`. If I then try to delete the now empty `aggregated` folder, `rm -rf aggregated` just sits there. Not sure how to debug/troubleshoot this.

Comment: is this `aggregated` at the root of the drive (`/media/myuser/toshiba/aggregated`)?

Comment: @xenoid no, it's in a subdir.

Comment: One possibility is that there is a bad sector involved that cannot be written to when the erasure happens. Is the disk very full? Did you check its SMART data?

Answer (score 3):

One of the fastest ways to delete files in Linux is to use Perl. Navigate to the parent directory and run the following command:

```
perl -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

If you do not feel comfortable with Perl, you can use the `find` command with the `-delete` flag to remove the files the files. The following will delete all files:

```
find ./ -type d,f -delete
```

Note: using the `-type d,f` will delete the files and directories, if you just want to delete the files use `-type f`

Here is an article that [benchmarks mass deleting files](https://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux) from a Linux system.

Comment: That article is old (what kernel version, what FS?) and is missing very obvious methods (such as using printf|xargs).

Answer (score 2):

Usually if a directory has too many and large files, running the command `rm -rf` will not help because it can cause the server to hang, this is the command that I usually use :

```
ls -1 | xargs rm -rfv
```

Some Output :

```
# ls -1 | xargs rm -rfv
removed 'NameOfFileOrDir'
```

Note:

- You must be in the directory, which will be deleted
- `ls -f` : Would list your file
- `xargs rm -rfv` : Would run delete with verbose

Hope this will help.

Comment: Care to elaborate why you think this is faster than `rm -rf /your-path`? IMO it’s the same (if not slower).

Comment: have you tried that ? :) 

First command make `rm -rf` run faster because it listing the file and directory first.

Make sure if your directory who want to delete have more 50GB size, and compare it with just `rm -rf` .

Comment: Ok, I just tried, and found that this command doesn’t work at all; it doesn’t delete anything. My steps: create a file `touch /tmp/test/1.txt`, then `ls -1 -f /tmp/test | xargs rm -rfv`.

Comment: I tried your steps, its true not working too on my side, edited : 

you must go to /your-path ex: /tmp/test/ and then run `ls -1 | xargs rm -rfv` 

```
/tmp/test ~ $ ls -1 | xargs rm -rfv
removed '1.txt'
removed 'test1.img'
```

Thanks @FranklinYu

Comment: If so please update the answer? And welcome to Super User.

Comment: @YonzLeon the problem is `ls -1` (which is just `ls` when piped anyway). It will still try to sort entries. `ls -f` (`-f` as "fast") would output entries on-the-fly to the pipeline without waiting to have read all entries in order to sort them (but would include . and ..). Of course the correct command to use would not be `ls` but the (GNU variant of) `find` command with proper options. Still, `rm -r` is specialized at this task and can only be faster as long as it's fed a directory name, not its content (never use `*`: the *shell* will have to sort files).